# Use of ALL CAPS in Android app labels

Tags: discussion, android-app

Is it good netiquette/UX to ask the user to "ADD COMMENT" and "POST" now? I thought ALL CAPS was a thing of the past (using a typewriter with a stuck shift key was fun!)

Android app 1.0.68.

Relevant UX SE Q&As (some of them):

- [What's the deal with Windows 8 elements with ALL CAPS?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22258/whats-the-deal-with-windows-8-elements-with-all-caps)
- [Why is it that all caps text looks like SHOUTING, but all caps handwriting is easier to read?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34898/why-is-it-that-all-caps-text-looks-like-shouting-but-all-caps-handwriting-is-ea)
- [Uppercase for a mobile app](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/44565/uppercase-for-a-mobile-app)
- [Should we use 'Title Case' or 'Sentence case' for headlines and buttons?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28297/should-we-use-title-case-or-sentence-case-for-headlines-and-buttons/48620#48620)

Comment: I NEVER STARTED TO TRULY HATE ALL CAPS UNTIL MICROSOFT STARTED DOING IT.

Comment: EVEN WORSE is that MICROSOFT vary IT RANDOMLY

Comment: I Prefer this To A severe case of Random Capital letter Syndrome. at least Its Consistent.

Comment: It's kind of a dilemma when trying to follow the current design guideline of Google, [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-usage): the text on the button is ALL CAPS. However, SE doesn't follow it completely, as "Add an answer" is written in sentence case. As for the text on the top bar (or technically, the [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)), it's ALL CAPS by default.